# How to control a robot from Gazebo using ROS2 Foxy?

Tags: c++, ros2, gazebo-simu, ignition

I'm utterly confused by the Gazebo/Ignition simulation programs. I'm currently using ROS2 Foxy with Ubuntu 20.04 and looking forward to controlling an UAV modeled in Gazebo via ROS2. However I'm completely lost even though there's "documentation" (which I've found it to be really mixed up between all the different versions of ROS).

What I've done so far is trying to run this script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ignition/msgs.hh>
 
int main()
{
  ignition::msgs::Vector3d point1;
  point1.set_x(1);
  point1.set_y(3);
  point1.set_z(5);
  ignition::msgs::Vector3d point2;
  point2.set_x(2);
  point2.set_y(4);
  point2.set_z(6);
 
  std::cout << "Point1:\n" << point1.DebugString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Point2:\n" << point2.DebugString() << std::endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

However I get the message that the build fails since there is no ignition directory even though I have installed it.

I'd appreciate any help in this matter since I feel I'm completely lost with installations and the CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gustavo,

with this `CMakeLists.txt` you can compile your code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2 FATAL_ERROR)

find_package(gz-cmake3 REQUIRED)

project(message-example)

gz_find_package(gz-msgs9 REQUIRED)
set(GZ_MSGS_VER ${gz-msgs9_VERSION_MAJOR})

add_executable(message-example main.cpp)
set_property(TARGET message-example PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_link_libraries(message-example
  PRIVATE gz-msgs${GZ_MSGS_VER}::gz-msgs${GZ_MSGS_VER})
```

then execute

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
./message-example
```

I don't know which Gazebo version are you using but the version for `gz-msgs` might be different:

- Garden - msgs9
- Fortress - msgs8
- Citadel - msgs5

You can find here some [examples related with Gazebo](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim7/examples) or if you are going to use Gazebo and ROS you should review this other repository [ros_gz](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz).

Comment: Thank you kindly @ahcorde, this was a project I left to rest for a bit, hence the long long time it took me to answer. I've recently got to it again and it worked like a charm. Much appreciated!